# Upgrading elastic7 to elastic8 no reindexing required?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-8

I just did a test upgrade from elastic 7.17.11 to 8.8.2 and was able to use my old indices and write to them without reindexing to a new index. The only information I found was upgrading from 5.x or 6.x to 8 - but nothing is stating required steps to upgrade from 7.17.x to 8.x.

Is reindexing no more required?
What happens when upgrading to some future 9.x?
Will I have to reindex

- before going to 9
- after going to 9
- or not at all?

Answer (score 1):

It's stated in the [official documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup-upgrade.html)

> To upgrade to 8.8.2 from 7.16 or an earlier version, you must first upgrade to 7.17

and also in the [upgrade guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elastic-stack/8.8/upgrading-elastic-stack.html#prepare-to-upgrade):

> To upgrade to 8.8.2 from 7.16 or earlier, you must first upgrade to 7.17. This enables you to use the Upgrade Assistant to identify and resolve issues, **reindex indices created before 7.0**, and then perform a rolling upgrade.

So if you're already on 7.17, then you're good to upgrade to 8 without reindexing. You only need to reindex if you have indices created before 7.0

Also worth noting that starting in 8.3, it is now possible to [read/search indices created in older versions](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/archive-indices.html) (5, 6) without reindexing them but with certain conditions.

Comment: It's still a bit confusing. Recently every major version jump required reindexing.

I just made a test upgrade path by installing 7.9 -> 7.17 -> 8.8 and even though, I had to make the intermdiate step with 7.17 no reindexing was required along the way.

Comment: As far as I can remember, every major version upgrade required to upgrade to the latest minor version of the previous major version. [Rolling upgrades](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/rolling-upgrades.html) (i.e. without reindexing) have always been supported between minor versions and from 5.6 to 6.8 and 6.8 to 7.17. It was a bit better described in the [upgrade procedure to 7.x](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/setup-upgrade.html)